# how do i return back to a tabbar controller main window?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, tabbar

in my app I have a button on my first tab page that leads to a new view with a `webview` on it.  I have added a back button to a `navigation bar` at the top and coded it to go back to the first tab `window` however when it loads it doesn't have the tab bar at the bottom.  here is the code for the `IBAction` for the back button.  can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong.  I am pretty new at this so I'm sorry if it is a simple fix! thanks ahead of time!

```
-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    HomeTab *homeTab = [[HomeTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeTab" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self presentModalViewController:homeTab animated:YES];
}
```

(HomeTab is the item 1 on the tab bar)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```